# Ruby 'net/ssh' & using logic in ruby based on bash cmd response

Tags: ruby, system-administration

Using Ruby 'net/ssh' can I set a variable in ruby based on the output of a bash cmd in the target system log into? The target system does not have ruby installed. From my shell (has ruby obviously)...

For example (this works and returns the hostnames):

```
hosts = ['10.4.5.12', '10.4.5.18']
cmd = "/bin/hostname;"

hosts.each do |host|
    begin
         Net::SSH.start(host , username, :password => password, :paranoid=>false) $
         puts "\n#{host}\n"
         puts ssh.exec! cmd
         puts "\n"
    end
         rescue Timeout::Error
         puts "#{host} Timed out"
         rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
         puts "#{host} Host unreachable"
         rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
         puts "#{host} Connection refused"
         rescue Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
         puts "#{host} Authentication failure"
    end
end
```

I want to use some additional logic in my script based on the output of 'cmd'. If the hostname is x do this... I want to do this in ruby - not bash.. Make sense? So in my ruby script -> test = output from cmd on target system (bash only) and then if test == x I'll run a second command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use syntax like this

```
test = %x[ bash command ]
```

for example

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > command = %x[ echo "Hello world" ]
=> "Hello world\n"
```

You can also check the return code of last command by calling

```
$?.exitstatus
```

Comment: How does this help the OP?